# Jquery image Zoomer function not getting called

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, zooming

I am trying to implement the image zoom found on [this website](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm), but I am having issues getting it to work in my website. I add the .js and .css files to the root and referenced the files in javascript as instructed, but it seems i never reach jquery function. What am I doing wrong? I get no errors on the page. When I hover over the image nothing happens.

```
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multizoom.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="multizoom.js">
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [300, 300],
        magnifierpos: 'right',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: 'someImage.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
    })
})
</script>

</head>

 <img id="image1" border="0" src="someImagesmall.jpg" style="width:250px;height:338px">
```

Comment: I know it's obvious, but you put the dependent files in question on your server right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="multizoom.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [300, 300],
        magnifierpos: 'right',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: 'someImage.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: which error message does popping up with error console (shift-ctrl J) giving you?

Comment: Yes, I had it this way before, but I just adjusted according to your suggestion, and same results.

Comment: Do you have the solution already? You need yet another script tag before those that includes jquery.js

Comment: I see, I didn't include jquery.js. I'm going to see if this fixes the issue.